# Get the text from the nested span tag with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have an `html` file:

```
...
<span class="value">401<span class="Suffix">st</span></span>
...
```

and I want to get only first `span` tag text which is `401` but when I run:

```
>>> get_text = soup.find(class_ = 'value').text
>>> print(get_text)
401st
```

the output contains inner spans text(`st`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work fine:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s = '''<span class="value">401<span class="Suffix">st</span></span>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'html.parser')
get_text = soup.find(class_='value')
print(get_text.contents[0])
```

**Output**

```
401
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.strings`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings). This is a `@property` that gives a generator of individual string elements. `.text` or `.get_text` is what joins those strings together.

```
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup('<span class="value">401<span class="Suffix">st</span></span>')
>>> t = soup.find(class_='value')
>>> next(t.strings)
'401'
>>> list(t.strings)
['401', 'st']
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `recursive=False` in `BeautifulSoup`

```
<span class="value">401<span class="Suffix">st</span></span>
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

all_parent_p = soup.find_all('p', recursive=False)
for parent_p in all_parent_p:
   ptext = parent_p.find(text=True, recursive=False)
```